# Vue 3 composition API remove columns from DxDatagrid

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, devextreme, dx-data-grid

I need to remove a column from my DxDataGrid after get the columns from datasource.
Here a codesandbox of the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/web-api-service-devextreme-data-grid-forked-kqloix?file=/package.json